# Ajax submit button not working on PHP/HTML form

Tags: php, html, ajax, submit

The submit button not working please help

with `Ajax` code on `PHP` form when I click on continue nothing happens at all see source code bellow

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
<div
    style="display:none;"
    class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 no-margin sm-margin-bottom xs-margin-top-screen-md xs-margin-bottom-screen-sm"
    id="errorUserID"
    ng-show="loginForm.userId.$invalid &amp;&amp; (loginForm.userId.$touched || loginForm.$submitted)"
    >
    <span class="icon-alert red-icon" icon-bg="red" icon="alert"></span>
    <span class="text-bold text-std" ng-transclude="" translate="">Please enter a value</span>
</div>
```

---

`Ajax` code:

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userId = $('#userId').val();

    if (userId == null || userId == '') {
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'files/action.php?type=login',
        data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var parsed_data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (parsed_data.status == 'ok') {
                //console.log(parsed_data); 
                location.href = "Loading.php"   
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Do you know how to use your browser's Developer Tools to look for errors etc?

Comment: no i dont, can you help out please?

Comment: well if you're using popular browsers like Chrome or Firefox, they already have tutorials online showing you how to use the developer tools. To begin with, you can open them by pressing F12 in most browsers. At the least, you should be a) checking the Console in case there are JavaScript errors preventing your script from executing, then b) checking the Network tab to see if the AJAX call is happening when you press submit on your form, and see what result comes back from the server.

Comment: And c) you can also use the Javascript debugger to step through your JS code line by line - this can help you to confirm that your event is actually firing to to begin with, and what path your code is taking through the various `if` statements etc.